# Delphi Linux64: how to retrieve the version information set by Project Options Version?

Tags: linux, delphi, version

I gather there is no universal standard for putting version numbers into executables on Linux, in contrast to Windows which requires a certain structure for those details.

[FreePascal has made its own standard](http://wiki.freepascal.org/Show_Application_Title,_Version,_and_Company#Linux) and [Delphi lets you define Version information](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Tokyo/en/Version_Info) for a Linux executable.

If we can put Version information in, we must be able to get it back out?  How? Specifically on Linux64?

I have searched *.pas and *.inc in Studio\19.0\source\rtl\posix  and I have not found anything on 'version' nor 'fileinfo' that could help.

Back with Kylix, I used to use argp_program_version from libc.

On a clean new DUnitX project, after adding {$ *.res} to the DPR so that the version information will stick, I can look at Project Options for Linux64 and I can see that they have a CFBundleVersion number defaulting to 1.0.0 for the project.  How can I get the CFBundleVersion at runtime in my Linux64 executable?

Or, if that is not possible, could/should Delphi match the FreePascal standard and put the fileinfo into something which both Lazarus and Delphi could view at runtime??

Comment: What Delphi *should/could do* is entirely up to EMBT, and you should discuss that on their forums. It's irrelevant here; the URL in the location bar of your browser does not contain *embarcadero.com*, so we have no influence over what they *should/could* do.

Answer (score 0):

This excerpt (metioned at both Windows and MacOS/iOS sections) from https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Alexandria/en/Version_Info may help:

> Go to Tools > Options > IDE > Environment Variables and add a new User variable called SAVEVRC with Value=TRUE. This variable enables the generation of a .vrc file with an auto generated build number and other information.

another excerpt from there (not sure if related to the aforementioned SAVEVRC or not) is:

> Note: If you define the VersionInfo resource and add it to the project via a $R directive in the project file, the compiler will ignore settings of Version Info at Project Options dialog box and use the custom resource data instead, given an application can have only one VersionInfo resource on Windows.